# MonacaのiBeconサンプルアプリが上手く動作させられません。

Tags: monaca, bluetooth, ibeacon

Monacaで新規に、iBeaconプロジェクトを作成し、
Cordovaプラグインに、ProximityBeaconPlugin v3.3.0 を設定し、
ビーコン情報に、UniqueID / ProximityUUID / Major# / Minor# を設定し、
デバッグ機（iPhone6plus）で、実行しましたが iBeacon を認識出来ない様です。
iBecon機器にはAplixのMyBeaconを利用し専用アプリで電波は確認できています。

このサンプルプロジェクトを実行するには、他に何か設定が必要なのでしょうか？

このサンプルプロジェクトを正常に動作させられてる方いらっしゃいますか？